# Select particular value and condition dependency more than one row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
id  certificate_id   coach_id
1         2              7
2         3              7
3         2              8
```

We have data like this, we need to select that coach_id who has the certificate_id 2 and 3.  So, here i need to select coach_id = 7.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: This isn't a question, open the mysql documentation and look for where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT coach_id
FROM your_table 
WHERE certificate_id IN (2,3)
GROUP BY coach_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2;
```